# Passing directories to hadoop streaming : some help needed

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, hadoop, streaming, amazon-emr

The context is that I am trying to run a streaming job on Amazon EMR *(the web UI)* with a bash script that I run like:

```
-input s3://emrdata/test_data/input -output s3://emrdata/test_data/output -mapper
s3://emrdata/test_data/scripts/mapperScript.sh -reducer NONE
```

The input directory has sub-directories in it and these sub-directories have gzipped data files.

The relevant part of `mapperScript.sh` that fails is :

```
for filename in "$input"/*; do

dir_name=`dirname $filename`
fname=`basename $filename`

echo "$fname">/dev/stderr

modelname=${fname}.model

modelfile=$model_location/$modelname

echo "$modelfile">/dev/stderr

inputfile=$dirname/$fname

echo "$inputfile">/dev/stderr

outputfile=$output/$fname

echo "$outputfile">/dev/stderr

# Will do some processing on the files in the sub-directories here

done # this is the loop for getting input from all sub-directories
```

Basically, I need to read the sub-directories in streaming mode and when I run this, hadoop complains saying :

```
2013-03-01 10:41:26,226 ERROR
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation (main):               
PriviledgedActionException as:hadoop cause:java.io.IOException: Not a
file:      s3://emrdata/test_data/input/data1 2013-03-01 10:41:26,226
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob (main):  Error Launching
job : Not a file: s3://emrdata/test_data/input/data1
```

I am aware that a similar q has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095717/pass-directories-not-files-to-hadoop-streaming)

The suggestion there was to write one's own InputFormat. I am wondering if I am missing something else in the way my script is written / EMR inputs are given, or whether writing my own InputFormat in Java is my only choice.

I have tried giving my input with a "input/*" to EMR as well, but no luck.

Comment: Did you already have a look at http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3 and checked your settings of fs.default.name etc.?

Comment: did you also try `input path/*/*`?

Comment: Michael, yes I did do that. Those settings seem fine, and moreover, work perfectly when there are no sub-directories being passed to the streaming script.

Comment: Amar - nope, have not tried that. I will do that and check if it helps, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that while there may be some temporary workarounds to this, but inherently hadoop doesn't support this yet as you may see that there is an open ticket on this [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-3193). 
So `inputpatth/*/*` may work for 2 level of subdierctories it may fail for further nesting.

The best thing you can do for now is get the listing of the files/folders-without-any-subdirectory and add them recursively after creating a csv list of inputPaths. You may use sinple tools like [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) for this.